# Is it possible to get a "track length list" from Audacity?

Tags: audacity

I have an Audacity project (well, actually several), and I want to use it with a set of slides to create a video.  To progress the slides at the appropriate time, I need to know the exact length of each track.

I know Audacity has this information, and I can get it out by manually highlighting each track, looking at the bottom (after changing the drop-down to "Start and Length of Selection"), and then typing that into another file ... but surely there's an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear (sadly) that there is no way to extract the length of each track from an Audacity project.  Hopefully the Audacity team will remedy this someday, and then I can change the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you'd be better off using a command-line tool such as [`mediainfo`](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo).

You can get the duration (in ms) of audio tracks from one or more files:

```
$ mediainfo --Output="Audio;%Duration%" filename
193306
```

Output can be formatted in different ways:

```
$ mediainfo --Output="Audio;%Duration/String%" filename
3mn 13s
$ mediainfo --Output="Audio;%Duration/String1%" filename
3mn 13s 306ms
$ mediainfo --Output="Audio;%Duration/String3%" filename
00:03:13.306
```

It can process multiple files at once:

```
$ mediainfo --Output="Audio;%Duration/String%\n" file1 file2 file3
3mn 13s
2mn 12s
4mn 14s

$ mediainfo --Output="Audio;%Duration/String%\n" *.mp3
2mn 47s
3mn 18s
4mn 35s
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't really help my case.  My audacity files have 20+ tracks, and I need  to get the lengths of each of those tracks.  If I serialize the file to MP3 I'll only get the length of the entire (20+) set of tracks.  Plus, even if I could serialize every track to a separate mp3, it would take a lot longer to do that and run `mediainfo` than it would to do what I'm currently doing (clicking on each track and typing out its length in a separate file).  But this seems like a great solution for non-Audacity users.